# Creating a primary key data health expectation in Palantir Foundry Code Repositories

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I have a dataset that is the output of a Python transform defined in Palantir Foundry Code Repository. It has a primary key, but given that over time the data may change I want to validate this primary key holds in the future.

How can I create a data health expectation or check to ensure the primary key holds in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define data expectations in your Python transform, for example:

```py
from transforms.api import transform_df, Input, Output, Check
from transforms import expectations as E


@transform_df(
    Output("/path/to/output", checks=[
        Check(E.primary_key("thing_id"), "primary_key: thing_id"),
    ]),
    source_df=Input("/path/to/input"),
)
def compute(source_df):
    return source_df.select("thing_id", "thing_name").distinct()
```

More information is available in the [Palantir Foundry documentation on defining data expectations](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/maintaining-pipelines/define-data-expectations/).